# XmlSerializer causes XamlParseException

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, exception, serialization

I have a simple WPF app and when I try to serialize a simple Exception with XmlSerializer, I get a XamlParseException.

The code in MainWindow.xaml is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

The code in App.xaml is:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

The code of Serializer static class used for serialization is:

```
public static class Serializer<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// serialize an instance to xml
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="instance"> instance to serialize </param>
    /// <returns> instance as xml string </returns>
    public static string Serialize(T instance)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// deserialize an xml into an instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml"> xml string </param>
    /// <returns> instance </returns>
    public static T Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            foreach (Type t in types)
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t);
                if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
                    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// store all derived types of T:
    /// is used in deserialization
    /// </summary>
    private static Type[] types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                                        .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                                            && t.IsClass
                                            && !t.IsGenericType)
                                            .ToArray();
}
```

The code in MainWindow.xaml.cs is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
  /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Exception e = new System.IO.IOException("blablabla", new System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException());
        MessageBox.Show(Serializer<Exception>.Serialize(e));
    }
   }
  }
```

And when I run this, I get this exception:

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'WpfApplication2.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding
>   constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position
>   '9'.

What can be the problem?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall That was not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would have seen if you had tested it out as an **isolated problem** was that the `XmlSerializer` throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the message

> There was an error reflectig type 'System.IO.IOException'.

The inner exception holds a detailed description why:

> Cannot serialize member System.Exception.Data of type System.Collections.IDictionary, ...

Dictionaries cannot be serialized with the .NET XML Serializer. That's that.